# Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority Intermediate Certificate and iOS

Tags: ios, macos

On February 14, 2016, the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority Intermediate Certificate will expire.
I understand how this will affect Mac OS X apps.
Will this also have an affect on iOS apps?

Comment: You should some critical problem about that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services/35399656#35399656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this gem of a page.
https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Who needs to take action?
Developers who provide passes for Apple Wallet, deliver Safari Push Notifications, or create Safari Extensions need to download the renewed certificate, and take the following action:

- Apple Wallet Passes
- Mac Apps
- Safari Extensions
- Safari Push Notifications

So - if your iOS app is using the Apple Wallet Passes:

> Update your pass signing server to replace the expired certificate
>   with the renewed certificate by February 14, 2016. After this date,
>   apps that generate passes for Apple Wallet will not be able to install
>   new passes until the server has been updated.
>
> To test and verify your Apple Wallet Passes will behave correctly, set
>   the date on your pass signing server and your iOS development device
>   to February 15, 2016 or later. Restart your systems and sign and
>   install your passes on a device.
>
> To test and verify your iOS apps will behave correctly, set the date
>   on your iOS development device to February 15, 2016 or later. Restart
>   your device and launch your apps.

Answer (score 4):

For both iOS and OSX, download the new certificate from [here](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer), install it in the keychain (double click).
Don't forget to remove the old certificate, otherwise Xcode won't recognize the new one.

> in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Select 'Show Expired Certificates' in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate.

Comment: This is the renewed certificate: `https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer`